# Angular template variable reference

Tags: javascript, html, web, angular2

Here is a weird problem in Angular:

```
<input #pin1 type="password">
<p>You entered: {{pin1.value}}</p>
```

If you type something in `<input>`, the `<p>`'s content will not change which means `pin1.value` does not have value, does it mean the variable reference `#pin1` does not work?

On the other hand, if we add a function to pass the reference, it will work.

```
<input #pin2 type="password" (input)="test(pin2)">
<p>You entered: {{pin2.value}}</p>
```

where `test=function(x){console.log(x);}`

For this `<input>`, if we type something, the the `<p>`'s content will change to corresponding text which implies `#pin2` works.

So I do not understand why we must do it? why we must use function to pass variable reference firstly then we can use it? Why can't we just declare a variable reference, and then directly use it in template expression or interpolation?

Comment: Consider use *[(ngModel)]="something"* on the input, and *{{ something }}* on the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngmodel to bind to values in the template:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
  required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

or as a component:

```
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
      <input name="last" ngModel>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <p>First name value: {{ first.value }}</p>
    <p>First name valid: {{ first.valid }}</p>
    <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>
    <p>Form valid: {{ f.valid }}</p>
  `,
})
export class SimpleFormComp {
  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f.value);  // { first: '', last: '' }
    console.log(f.valid);  // false
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Angular - NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)
- [Angular - Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)